# Access all tables in a html page with unknown numbers of table

Tags: java, htmlunit

I would like access  all tables iterating in a web page with unknown numbers of tables. I have written this code

```
import java.io.*; 
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;


public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            HtmlPage currentPage = client.getPage("http://www.mysite.com");
            client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("index.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
         final HtmlTable table =(HtmlTable)    currentPage.getByXPath("//table").get(i);
         for (final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
                for (final HtmlTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
                out.write(cell.asText()+',');
                }
         out.write('\n');
    }
}

out.close();
    client.closeAllWindows();

}
}
```

i have tried with checking condition:

```
  while(currentPage.getByXPath("//table")){....}
```

but is not accepted. What is the correct checking condition?

Comment: 1) Remove all those redundant blank lines (I did it for you in the posted sample) 2) Make it readable by using a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 3) Ask a *specific* question that does not equate to 'can someone complete this skeleton for me?'.

Comment: i agree on the points 1 and 2. but disagree in 3. my questions are not specific because i am making questions where i have no knowledge or very basic knowledge. Even more i would be very happy to be more specific if i could find a satisfactory documentation on this argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

htmlunit.html.HtmlPage has a method
    getElementsByTagName(String tagName)

where you can pass it the tagName of "table".  Then just get the length of how many it returns, in rough pseudocode:

```
var x = getElementsByTagName("table");
var nTables = x.length
```

Comment: the tag name change every times.

Comment: Are you sure you mean tag name?  Tag name is the element name.  And the element you are looking for is <TABLE>  and "table" is the tag.  I'm not sure how it can change every time

Answer (score -1):

First get list of HTML Table Rows. Then get list of HTMLTable columns and use for loops and iterate table.and check condition what you want

```
List<HtmlTableRow> tableRows = table.getRows();
```

I get row zero because I want to check table header if you want you can change as you want

```
List<HtmlTableCell> tableColumns = table.getRow(0).getCells();

for (int row = 0; row < tableRows.size(); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < tableColumns.size(); column++)
    {
        if (tableColumns.get(column).asText().equalsIgnoreCase("check your condition"))
        {
            // do what you want 
        } 
    }
}
```